# How to open a file relative to imported .py file

Tags: python

Please note - **this is NOT a duplicate of "how to open a file in the same folder as running script".** I'm trying to do the opposite of it - I want to open the file in the root folder of the imported .py file, rather than the root of main.py which is the running script.

My file structure is as follows:

```
/email_sender/sender.py
/email_sender/template.html
main.py
```

Inside the main.py file I am importing the sender.py

My question is how to refer correctly to template.html from inside of the `sender.py` file?
The following doesn't work because it expectes the template.html to be in the root folder (where main.py is).

I know I can hardcode the path, but is it possible to refer to it in relation to `sender.py`?

```
with open('template.html', 'r') as f:
    html = f.read()
```

Comment: You could parse `__file__` which holds a separate path string for current script. `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'template.html')`

Comment: Can you please elaborate which context are you running in? What is the CWD?

Comment: `__file__` is the full path to _the current python script file_, in this case `sender.py`. The template file you want to access is in the same directory.  So yes, I think this **is** a duplicate.  Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what "the running script" means.  `__file__` always refers to _this python source file_, no matter what module was executed as the "main" script.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from sys import argv

try:
    path = os.path.dirname(argv[0])
    os.chdir(path)
except:
    pass
```

You can do this in the main.py file and then to open the template will always be:

```
./email_sender/template.html
```

Comment: This will only work if `sys.argv[0]` is a full path.  I'm not sure you can count on that.